# Detecting gestures out of touch points

Tags: qt

I have this method to detect gestures according to touch event type:

```
void Viewport::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        qDebug() << __func__ << "Touch beings: " << event->type();
        break;
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        qDebug() << __func__ << "Touch ends: " << event->type();
        break;
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
        qDebug() << __func__ << "Touch updates: "<< event->type();
        break;
    case QEvent::TouchCancel:
        qDebug() << __func__ << "Touch cancels: " << event->type();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }    
}
```

I'm looking for a Qt tool to **detect touch gestures** like pinch-in and pinch-out. My understanding of [this page](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/gestures-overview.html) is that `QGestureEvent` and `QGesture` can be used only with widgets. I wonder if Qt has any gesture recognition tool which can work anywhere even without widgets.

Comment: What do you mean without widgets? Qt only manages and detects the events that concern them, that is to say that the focus is within the application. I think you should use OS tools to get data and try to implement algorithms (or maybe use a library that has it implemented) to perform the task you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc I implemented an algorithm to detect pinch gesture on touch screen. I posted my algorithm as an answer. I'm not sure if it is the best which I can come up with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I developed a homebrew algorithm for detecting pinch gestures like this:

```
void Viewport::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate: // Only consider "update" case, does it make sense?
        if(/* Everything is OK */) {
            detectGesturePinch(event); // Method containing the detection algorithm
            event->accept();
        }
        else
            event->ignore();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

The actual pinch gesture detection algorithm:

```
void Viewport::detectGesturePinch(QTouchEvent *event)
{
    // We are concerned with two fingers on touch screen, not more, not less
    if (event->touchPoints().length() == 2) {
        QTouchEvent::TouchPoint point1 = event->touchPoints().at(0);
        QTouchEvent::TouchPoint point2 = event->touchPoints().at(1);

        qDebug() << __func__ << "Point 1 state: " << point1.state();
        qDebug() << __func__ << "Point 2 state: " << point2.state();
        qDebug() << __func__ << "Point 1: " << point1;
        qDebug() << __func__ << "Point 2: " << point2;

        // Both fingers should be moving, right?
        if (point1.state() == Qt::TouchPointMoved &&
                point2.state() == Qt::TouchPointMoved) {

            qDebug() << __func__ << " Both points moving";

            QVector2D vec1 = QVector2D(point1.pos() - point1.lastPos());
            QVector2D vec2 = QVector2D(point2.pos() - point2.lastPos());
            vec1.normalize();
            vec2.normalize();

            // The relative angle of two fingers moving
            // Dot product gives a measure of relative angle
            qreal angleFactor = QVector2D::dotProduct( vec1, vec2);

            // To see if two fingers are moving apart or moving toward eachother
            QVector2D delta = QVector2D(point1.pos() - point2.pos());
            QVector2D lastDelta = QVector2D(point1.lastPos() - point2.lastPos());

            if ( angleFactor < m_gesturePinchAngleThreshold && delta.length() > lastDelta.length() ) {
                qDebug() << __func__ << "Angle factor: " << angleFactor << "Gesture is pinch-out!";
            }
            if ( angleFactor < m_gesturePinchAngleThreshold && delta.length() < lastDelta.length() ) {
                qDebug() << __func__ << "Angle factor: " << angleFactor << "Gesture is pinch-in!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `m_gesturePinchAngleThreshold` of type `double` can be initialized as `0.8` for example, to control the relative angle of two pinching fingers.